# Preloading of chain of complex/indirect ActiveRecord functions/'associations'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working on a plugin for [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/), which means that I can modify classes with class_eval, but I cannot change the DB schema. To store extra data about the Topic model, I can perform joins with TopicCustomField, which is provided for this purpose.

I am able to store and retrieve all the data I need, but when many Topics are loaded at once, the DB performance is inefficient because my indirect data is loaded once for each Topic by itself. It would be much better if this data were loaded all at once for each Topic, like can happen when using preload or includes.

For example, each Topic has a topic_guid, and a set of parent_guids (stored in a single string with dashes because order is important). These parent_guids point to both other Topic's topic_guids as well as the name of other Groups.

I would love to be able write something like:

```
has_many :topic_custom_fields
has_many :parent_guids, -> { where(name: 'parent_guids').pluck(:value).first }, :through => :topic_custom_fields
has_many :parent_groups, class_name: 'Group', primary_key: :parent_guids, foreign_key: :name
```

But this :through complains about not being able to find an association ":parent_guids" in TopicCustomField, and primary_key won't actually take an association instead of a DB column.

I've also tried the following, but the :through clauses are not able to use the functions as associations.

```
has_many :topic_custom_fields do
    def parent_guids
        parent_guids_str = where(name: PARENT_GUIDS_FIELD_NAME).pluck(:value).first
        return [] unless parent_guids_str
        parent_guids_str.split('-').delete_if { |s| s.length == 0 }
    end
    def parent_groups
        Group.where(name: parent_guids)
    end
end

has_many :parent_guids, :through => :topic_custom_fields
has_many :parent_groups, :through => :topic_custom_fields
```

Using Rails 4.2.7.1

Comment: Looks like the general strategy for custom preloading is here: https://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope there is a more elegant solution, but this is what I have done in order to preload my data efficiently. This should be fairly easy to extend to other applications.

I modify Relation's exec_queries, which calls other preloading functions.

```
ActiveRecord::Relation.class_eval do
    attr_accessor :preload_funcs

    old_exec_queries = self.instance_method(:exec_queries)
    define_method(:exec_queries) do |&block|
        records = old_exec_queries.bind(self).call(&block)
        if preload_funcs
            preload_funcs.each do |func|
                func.call(self, records)
            end
        end
        records
    end
end
```

To Topic, I added:

```
has_many :topic_custom_fields
attr_accessor :parent_groups

def parent_guids
    parent_guids_str = topic_custom_fields.select { |a| a.name == PARENT_GUIDS_FIELD_NAME }.first
    return [] unless parent_guids_str
    parent_guids_str.value.split('-').delete_if { |s| s.length == 0 }
end
```

And then in order to preload the parent_groups, I do:

```
def preload_parent_groups(topics)
    topics.preload_funcs ||= []
    topics.preload_funcs <<= Proc.new do |association, records|
        parent_guidss = association.map {|t| t.parent_guids}.flatten
        parent_groupss = Group.where(name: parent_guidss).to_a

        records.each do |t|
            t.parent_groups = t.parent_guids.map {|guid| parent_groupss.select {|group| group.name == guid }.first}
        end
    end
    topics
end
```

And finally, I add the preloaders to my Relation query:

```
result = result.preload(:topic_custom_fields)
result = preload_parent_groups(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `through` parameter of rails associations is to set a many-to-many association with a model, passing "through" other model:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

So you can't do

```
has_many :parent_guids, :through => :topic_custom_fields
```

since `ParentGuid` is not a model related to `TopicCustomFields`. Also, pass a block to `has_many` is only to extend the association with new methods as the ones rails already provide you, like `topic_custom_fields.create`, `topic_custom_fields.build`, etc.

Why don't you define the methods inside the block at your second example in the `Topic` class to retrieve the groups? Is there something you want that would not be possible only with the methods?

**Update**

Well, I don't think it's possible achieve the same improved performance in this case, since the group ids still have to be handled from `topic_custom_fields`, and the improved performance is reached through JOINs. Maybe a complex combination of `preload`, `where` and `references` could do the trick, but I don't know if it's possible.

You could try to minimize the db calls instead, maybe gathering all the parent_guids before querying the groups.

Comment: I actually have had that working, but it results in sub-par performance, because those methods get evaluated individually for each Topic. For associations, I can do topics.preload(:topic_custom_fields) which loads all the relevant custom fields data with a single query for all of the topics at once. I would like to similarly be able to do topics.preload(:parent_guids),preload(:parent_groups), etc... I know that through doesn't work like this, so I'd like to find an alternative that can result in the same improved performance!